# Heap/Stack variables in objectiveC

Tags: objective-c

I just started programming in objectiveC. From what I understand is that all object are created on the heap such as

```
foo* f = [[foo alloc]init];
```

however I could not find any reference to default variables such as int . Is it safe to say that these variables are created on the stack say using an int inside a method?

Comment: You should have a working knowledge of C and also an understanding of objects a la C++ or Java before you attempt to use Objective-C.  Then you will understand the difference between a *pointer* (*reference* in Java) and a *primitive* value.  An `int` is a primitive value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All variables in a method are on the stack.

In your posted code, `f` is on the stack (assuming it's a variable inside a method). The object that `f` points to is on the heap.

Answer (score 0):

Objective-C is an extended C and primitive variables are the same as in C. So the answer is yes.